# What are the individual tests SunSpider JavaScript benchmark runs?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

Can someone explain to me what each [SunSpider](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/sunspider.html) subtest actually checks and give a real-life equivalent of their importance and use? Which outcomes (ie times) are considered acceptable for a modern system?

The only information I have found so far was generic [for each subsection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001023.html), at Coding Horror.

> **3d**    Pure JavaScript computations of the
>   kind you might use to do 3d rendering,
>   but without the rendering. This ends
>   up mostly hitting floating point math
>   and array access.
>
> **access**    Array, object property and
>   variable access.
>
> **bitops**    Bitwise operations, these can
>   be useful for various things including
>   games, mathematical computations, and
>   various kinds of encoding/decoding.
>   It's also the only kind of math in
>   JavaScript that is done as integer,
>   not floating point.
>
> **controlflow**   Control flow constructs
>   (looping, recursion, conditionals).
>   Right now it mostly covers recursion,
>   as the others are pretty well covered
>   by other tests.
>
> **crypto**    Real cryptography code, mostly
>   covers bitwise operations and string
>   operations.
>
> **date**  Performance of JavaScript's
>   "date" objects.
>
> **math**  Various mathematical type
>   computations.
>
> **regexp**    Regular expressions. Pretty
>   self-explanatory.
>
> **string**    String processing, including
>   code to generate a giant "tagcloud",
>   extracting compressed JS code, etc.

**But what about the individual tests in each subsection?**

For example the "access" subsection has 4 tests (`binary-trees, fannkuch, nbody, nsieve`). What does each calculate and why/when should be important in a real web application that makes use of JavaScript?

Comment: Some of those tests have nothing to do with real web applications or anything else. bitops-bitwise-and, in particular, runs a single bitwise and in a tight loop. What makes it especially awesome is that after the first time through the loop, the variable is always 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Jeff's comment 6-th from the top in your linked article. He tells you how to view the details behind each specific test, although it won't actually give us the *reasoning* behind each specific test. For that you'll probably have to go to the source (the Apple Webkit team):

> Freiheit, I too wish there was more
>   documentation and explanation of each
>   test.
>
> Here's a complete list of the tests:
>
> var tests = [ "3d-cube", "3d-morph",
>   "3d-raytrace", "access-binary-trees",
>   "access-fannkuch", "access-nbody",
>   "access-nsieve",
>   "bitops-3bit-bits-in-byte",
>   "bitops-bits-in-byte",
>   "bitops-bitwise-and",
>   "bitops-nsieve-bits",
>   "controlflow-recursive", "crypto-aes",
>   "crypto-md5", "crypto-sha1",
>   "date-format-tofte",
>   "date-format-xparb", "math-cordic",
>   "math-partial-sums",
>   "math-spectral-norm", "regexp-dna",
>   "string-base64", "string-fasta",
>   "string-tagcloud",
>   "string-unpack-code",
>   "string-validate-input" ];
>
> To load each one, add it to the URL
>   like so:
>
> http://webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/3d-cube.html
>
> Then simply view source; each test is
>   contained in an embedded script tags
>   in the page.
>
> Jeff Atwood on December 19, 2007 7:54
>   PM

So for access-fannkuch, go to http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/access-fannkuch.html and view the source, which shows you the actual code of the test.

Some have some useful info or links in the source page.

Others appear to be somewhat "standard" programming language benchmarks. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Shootout/Fannkuch for example.

Others you'll just have to follow the logic of the function to see what they're actually doing.

Comment: 10 from The Computer Language Benchmarks Game - see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

10 from [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) -

["access-binary-trees"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=binarytrees)

["access-fannkuch"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/performance.php?test=fannkuch)

["access-nbody"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=nbody)

["access-nsieve"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/performance.php?test=nsieve)

["bitops-nsieve-bits"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/performance.php?test=nsievebits)

["controlflow-recursive"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/performance.php?test=recursive)

["math-partial-sums"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/performance.php?test=partialsums)

["math-spectral-norm"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=spectralnorm)

["regexp-dna"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=regexdna)

["string-fasta"](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=fasta)